# Updating Nuget Package in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, package, nuget

I have a problem updating the Nuget packages. I had to install my Visual Studio in a new environment and new is also Azure DevOps. Previously we had the TFS.

Meanwhile I have some packages on the Azure DevOps that I need for my Solution. In addition, packages from Nuget.org are still needed.

In my solution older versions of the Nuget packages are included. Some packages I can't update for some reasons.
Now I have a Nuget package that needs to be updated and here comes my problem. When I go to Tools --> Manage Nuget Package for Solutions... and click on Install, it brings me in the Preview Changes overview all packages that have an older version and wants to update all of them.

Where can I set it or what do I have to do, so that only the one package is updated, which I have selected? In my old environment it works normally.

Thanks.

Cheers

Comment: Are you trying to update across the solution, or in a single project? It would be helpful to see some screenshots showing the difference. If you think this is a bug, report it at https://github.com/NuGet/Home

Comment: Any update about this issue? Please let us know any feedback.

Comment: Yes, it works. Update package one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update one package for all the projects under the solution, you should right-click on the **solution**-->**Manage Nuget Packages for Solution**

[image]

This will update the package of all selected projects to one same version.

You could also right-click on the **project**-->**Manage nuget packages** to update the package one by one. It is definitely not as flexible as the above one .